# How to write data with defined token or user/password into InfluxDB 2.0

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I need to set an influxdb 2.0.3 to be able to write data into it with a defined set of user/pass or token.

My use case is to provide a software component before deploy influxdb, and this component need to have a predefined configuration to write into influxdb (is not possible to interact with api influxdb, just write operation is implemented).

I'm understand in documentation that a user/password is couldn' be used with this new release to write data, only token provide this feature. Is it true?

In other hand, a solution is to set manually a predefined token into influxdb, but I don't found this feature in a api / documentation.

Someone have another solution or a way to bypass this limitation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a token's string when creating one in InfluxDB. You will need to create one when you deploy it, and pass the newly created token to whatever software will be writing to InfluxDB.

Comment: It's a form of regression, because in the 1.0 we can write into database with a predefined user/pass and with the v2 we need to provide and interact with the database before be able to write.